# Firebase Real Time Database - Rest API - Pagination

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I set up a firebase real time database and access it in react js without sdk, just through https requests on REST API.

My Question : I checked the docs and other sources and it seems that its not possible to conduct pagination with that set up. Is that correct, means I need the firebase sdk in the frontend to enable such features?

Best,

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) and not [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). There are actually two different database services offered by Firebase.

Comment: Its a Realtime Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use range queries to pagina data

Have a look at this part of the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data

An axample REST API call would be

```
curl 'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy="$key"&startAt="b"&endAt="b\uf8ff"&print=pretty'
```